Probability distribution of stochastic process with independent increments asymptotically approaching Gaussian
I am independently working through van Kampen's Stochastic Processes in Physics and Chemistry. It's a rewarding book to work through, but I am having trouble with question 46 on pg. 89. Below is the question (screenshot also attached). Recommended reading on the subject also appreciated.

A Markov process $Z(t)$ whose transition probability has the form
$T_{\tau}(z_{2}|z_{1}) = T_{\tau}(z_{2}-z_{1})$
is called a process with independent increments. It is homogeneous but not stationary, nor a subensemble of a stationary process. In order that (2.1) is obeyed one must have
$\int e^{ikz}T_{\tau}(z)dz = e^{\tau \phi(k)} $
where $\phi(k)$ is some function with $\phi(0)=0$. Show that $P_{1}(z,t)$ becomes Gaussian for $t \rightarrow \infty$.

2.1 is defined in the book as
$P_{1|1}(z_{3}, t_{3}| z_{1}, t_{1}) = \int P_{1|1}(z_{3}, t_{3}| z_{2}, t_{2})P_{1|1}(z_{2}, t_{2}| z_{1}, t_{1})dz_{2}$
and is the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. The transition probability $T_{\tau}(z_{2}|z_{1})$ occurs over the time difference $\tau = t_{2} - t_{1}$.
van Kampen defines $P_{1}(z_{1}, t_{1})$ for non-stationary Markov processes on pg. 87 as $P_{1}(z_{1}, t_{1}) = T_{t_{1} -t_{0}} (z_{1}|z_{0})$.
So, for this problem the time-dependent probability should be $P_{1}(z_{2}, t_{2}) = T_{t_{2} - t_{1}} (z_{2} - z_{1})$.
The integral looks like a characteristic function. Based on the definition of $P_{1}$, I believe I can substitute it into the integral as follows
$\int e^{ikz} P_{1}(z_{1}, t_{1}) dz_{1} = e^{\tau \phi(k)} $
but I am having trouble seeing how this function relates to a Gaussian.
Happy to provide additional detail if needed.


What is equation 2.1 ? Thanks.

@markleeds It's the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. I wrote it in van Kampen's notation.

Hi: I found the link ( in the next comment ) which contains a proof of what is, as far as I can tell, what you want to prove. But, at a quick glance ( it would take me forever to read the attachment and, even then, I don't know if I would not get stuck somewere ) it doesn't use the chapman-kolomogorov equation directly. The approach issomewhat different from your framework so I don't know if its helpful. In the end, the same thing is proven.

https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/courses/592/lecture3.pdf
